# Angular ng-style is adding a style attribute that is then not kept in sync

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-style

My angular website gets data from a Web API back end, and initially a generic background is shown. But after login, the customer background image url is retrieved and used in my ng-style attribute.

When the page initially loads, a style attribute also appears that is not in the source code, that points the background to the default image.

But after login, even though ng-style now shows the correct background image url, the style attribute is still pointing to the default url.

If I manually refresh the page (with no cache in developer settings in Chrome), the style attribute is updated and the customer background is correctly displayed.

What's happening? Why would angular add a style attribute and then not keep it in sync?

**Source Code**

```
<div class="background-div" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{user.profile.Customer.BackgroundImageUrl || '../images/bg.jpg'}})'}"></div>
```

**Initial page load**

```
<div class="background-div" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(../images/bg.jpg)'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:10223/images/bg.jpg);"></div>
```

**After login**

```
<div class="background-div" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://megacorp.com/images/vipcustomer.jpg)'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:10223/images/bg.jpg);"></div>
```

**After forced no-cache refresh**

```
<div class="background-div" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://megacorp.com/images/vipcustomer.jpg)'}" style="background-image: url(http://megacorp.com/images/vipcustomer.jpg);"></div>
```

**Fixed Code**

```
  <div class="background-div"
       ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + (user.profile.Customer.BackgroundImageUrl || '../images/bg.jpg') + ')'}">
  </div>
```

Reopen:

IMHO, this question is different b/c it stays in html, and doesn't get into $digest and script, and shows the stages as the page is in different states. But I defer to your judgement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-style` shouldn't contain `{{}}` interpolation in it, you could use direct scope variable in it.

**Markup**

```
<div class="background-div" 
   ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+user.profile.Customer.BackgroundImageUrl || 
   '../images/bg.jpg'+')'}">
</div>
```

Comment: I had to put parenthesis around the expression so it would do the OR before the concatenation. Then it worked. See my edit showing the fix. Thanks!

Comment: @toddmo no never use interpolation parenthesis in `ng-style`

Comment: I meant I had to put `(` and `)`, not `{{` and `}}`. Thanks!

Comment: @toddmo oh I missunderstood above..Sorry and Thanks :) Glad to help you.. :)